# Book info Goodreads API

Tags: reactjs, xml-to-json

Trying to do a search on the Goodreads API for book information. At the same time I'm trying to convert the data from xml to json. I get this error when I do a search for a book

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.

and warning

> Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://www.goodreads.com/search/index.xml?key=PL6saHk8cIrLeeLG3eylg&q=halo with MIME type application/xml. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.

I installed xml2js package and placed it into my function like this

```
searchBooks = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const search = this.state.search;
    try {
        let res = await axios.get(
            `https://www.goodreads.com/search/index.xml?key=PL6saHk8cIrLeeLG3eylg&q=${search}`
        );
        let xml = res.data;
        parseString(xml, (error, res) => {
            this.setState({
                books: res.data
            });
        });
    } catch (error) {
        this.setState({ error });
    }
    console.log(this.state.books);
};
```

What do I need to fix?

Answer (score 2):

GoodReads API doesn't let you make an API call from front-end. (Refer to this [GoodReads forum question](https://www.goodreads.com/topic/show/17893514-cors-access-control-allow-origin)).
You need to make an API request from back-end service (e.g. nodejs server), or go through a proxy.

Setting up a proxy can be a pain, so you can call the API using [YQL](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yql) (Yahoo's Query Language) client.

So here is the workaround.

*⚠️ WARNING: This is not a good practice but writing it here for an academic purpose.
Please consider setting up your own back-end service to call the API.*

Calling YQL directly can be hairy, so you can use another library called, [proxyfy-url](https://www.npmjs.com/package/proxify-url), which gives you a proxified YQL URL.

```
var proxify = require('proxify-url');

...

get proxyfiedUrl() {
    // GoodReads API returns result in "XML" format.
    // "XML" is the "input" format fed into YQL
    let proxyUrl = proxify(this.url, { inputFormat: 'xml' });
    return proxyUrl;
}
```

*Shameless plug!*
If you want more information, I wrote about the same problem on my blog
[How to call GoodReads API using YQL](https://www.slightedgecoder.com/2017/06/20/call-goodreads-api-using-yql/)

Comment: Great solution at the time but for anyone reading this now be aware Yahoo have retired the YQL service so it no longer works unfortunately.

Comment: @Poc275 Thank you for the update. For a quick & dirty solution, one can use https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/ or build a simple Node.JS backend and deploy it on heroku or zeit. That's the workaround I've been doing nowadays.